# Highlight All Duplicate Cells if any of cells is empty in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Example in this link, provided by Matt](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h4Ds_8Mm1ArSFtt4R-YN6m-zJPbMbde74nOB7TTL-zk/edit)

I want to highlight all cells that have duplicates if and only if among the duplicates, there's a cell in another column that's empty. Using conditional formatting on Google Sheets.

```
DUPLICATE | A
DUPLICATE | C
DUPLICATE | F
```

These duplicate cells should **not** be highlighted because none of the columns next to it are blank.

```
DUPLICATE | B
DUPLICATE | 
DUPLICATE | G
```

All 3 duplicate cells should be highlighted because at least one duplicate cell as a column next to it that's blank.

Needless to say, it should not be highlighted if there are no duplicates. This is what I tried:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(L2:L),COUNTIF($D$2:D,D2)>1)
```

I also tried:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($D$2:D,D2)>1,ISBLANK(L2:L))
```

Both of these functions only highlight the cell that have duplicates and is blank on the column L, and does not highlight the remaining duplicates, presumably because their cells' L column is not blank.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically for this question.  If you paste some data in there it will be easier for people to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h4Ds_8Mm1ArSFtt4R-YN6m-zJPbMbde74nOB7TTL-zk/edit

Comment: Much appreciated. I filled out some examples and reasonings on that sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,"")*(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1)
```

[image]